# Cannot convert a char value to money. The char value has incorrect syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I am receiving an error "Cannot convert a char value to money.  The char value has incorrect syntax.", when I believe it is in error.  We are performing a select statement from a primary table, joining to another, then attempting to insert these values into another table.  The query is below:

```
 *--CREATE TABLE [ETL_Test_Source].[ETL].[Master_BAR_INS_XFER_TXN_FACT_NPR_0_ETL_Test_Source_No_valid_subdivisions]
 --   (
 --     Appl_Database_Id VARCHAR(256) ,
 --     Automatic_Transfer_Amount MONEY ,
 --     Batch_Date_Id DATETIME ,
 --     Bill_Number VARCHAR(256) ,
 --     Collector_Id VARCHAR(256) ,
 --     Crp_Bot_Comp_Val_Id VARCHAR(256) ,
 --     Facility_Id VARCHAR(256) ,
 --     Insurance_Id VARCHAR(256) ,
 --     Manual_Transfer_Amount MONEY ,
 --     Net_Transfer_Amount MONEY ,
 --     Patient_Account_Id VARCHAR(256) ,
 --     Transaction_Urn VARCHAR(256)
 --   )  
DECLARE @Database VARCHAR(256) = 'ETL_Test_Source' ,
    @RunDateTime DATETIME = 'Apr 19 2015  4:56PM' ,
    @ScheduleDateTime DATETIME = 'Apr 19 2015  4:56PM' ,
    @Subdivision VARCHAR(256) = 'No_valid_subdivisions' ,
    @DateAwareFromDateTime DATETIME = 'Jan  1 2000 12:00AM' ,
    @DateAwareThruDateTime DATETIME = 'Jan  1 2101 12:00AM';
INSERT  INTO [ETL_Test_Source].[ETL].[Master_BAR_INS_XFER_TXN_FACT_NPR_0_ETL_Test_Source_No_valid_subdivisions]
        ( [Appl_Database_Id] ,
          [Automatic_Transfer_Amount] ,
          [Batch_Date_Id] ,
          [Bill_Number] ,
          [Collector_Id] ,
          [Crp_Bot_Comp_Val_Id] ,
          [Facility_Id] ,
          [Insurance_Id] ,
          [Manual_Transfer_Amount] ,
          [Net_Transfer_Amount] ,
          [Patient_Account_Id] ,
          [Transaction_Urn]
        )
        SELECT  XFRTXN.SourceID ,
                XFRTXN.AutoXferAmount ,
                COLL.BatchDateTime ,
                COLL.BillNumber ,
                LEDG.Collector ,  
                FINS.Corporation ,
                VISIT.FacilityID ,
                XFRTXN.InsuranceID ,
                XFRTXN.ManualEdit ,
                XFRTXN.AutoXferAmount ,
                XFRTXN.BillingID ,
                XFRTXN.TransactionID
        FROM    [dbo].[BarTxnInsuranceDetail] AS XFRTXN
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[BarVisits] AS VISIT ON [VISIT].[BillingID] = [XFRTXN].[BillingID]
                                                             AND [VISIT].[SourceID] = [XFRTXN].[SourceID]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[BarVisitFinancialData] AS FINS ON [FINS].[BillingID] = [XFRTXN].[BillingID]
                                                             AND [FINS].[SourceID] = [XFRTXN].[SourceID]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[BarInsuranceLedger] AS LEDG ON [LEDG].[BillingID] = [XFRTXN].[BillingID]
                                                              AND [LEDG].[InsuranceID] = [XFRTXN].[InsuranceID]
                                                              AND [LEDG].[SourceID] = [XFRTXN].[SourceID]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[BarCollectionTransactions] AS COLL ON [COLL].[BillingID] = [XFRTXN].[BillingID]
                                                              AND [COLL].[SourceID] = [XFRTXN].[SourceID]
                                                              AND [COLL].[TransactionID] = [XFRTXN].[TransactionID]
        WHERE   COLL.Type IN ( 'p', 'A', 'R', 'P', 'q', 'm', 'v', 'b' )
                AND COLL.BatchDateTime BETWEEN @DateAwareFromDateTime
                                       AND     @DateAwareThruDateTime*
```

IT appears that COLL.SourceID, although defined as a VARCHAR in COLL, and the table we are inserting it into, SQL seems to think that it is a MONEY type.  It turns out, that all of the values that we happen to be selecting are integers.  This query is producing this error now, but was not before.  Now, when the query is edited to the following:

```
 --CREATE TABLE [ETL_Test_Source].[ETL].[Master_BAR_INS_XFER_TXN_FACT_NPR_0_ETL_Test_Source_No_valid_subdivisions]
 --   (
 --     Appl_Database_Id VARCHAR(256) ,
 --     Automatic_Transfer_Amount MONEY ,
 --     Batch_Date_Id DATETIME ,
 --     Bill_Number VARCHAR(256) ,
 --     Collector_Id VARCHAR(256) ,
 --     Crp_Bot_Comp_Val_Id VARCHAR(256) ,
 --     Facility_Id VARCHAR(256) ,
 --     Insurance_Id VARCHAR(256) ,
 --     Manual_Transfer_Amount MONEY ,
 --     Net_Transfer_Amount MONEY ,
 --     Patient_Account_Id VARCHAR(256) ,
 --     Transaction_Urn VARCHAR(256)
 --   )  
DECLARE @Database VARCHAR(256) = 'ETL_Test_Source' ,
    @RunDateTime DATETIME = 'Apr 19 2015  4:56PM' ,
    @ScheduleDateTime DATETIME = 'Apr 19 2015  4:56PM' ,
    @Subdivision VARCHAR(256) = 'No_valid_subdivisions' ,
    @DateAwareFromDateTime DATETIME = 'Jan  1 2000 12:00AM' ,
    @DateAwareThruDateTime DATETIME = 'Jan  1 2101 12:00AM';
INSERT  INTO [ETL_Test_Source].[ETL].[Master_BAR_INS_XFER_TXN_FACT_NPR_0_ETL_Test_Source_No_valid_subdivisions]
        ( [Appl_Database_Id] ,
          [Automatic_Transfer_Amount] ,
          [Batch_Date_Id] ,
          [Bill_Number] ,
          [Collector_Id] ,
          [Crp_Bot_Comp_Val_Id] ,
          [Facility_Id] ,
          [Insurance_Id] ,
          [Manual_Transfer_Amount] ,
          [Net_Transfer_Amount] ,
          [Patient_Account_Id] ,
          [Transaction_Urn]
        )
        SELECT  XFRTXN.SourceID ,
                XFRTXN.AutoXferAmount ,
                COLL.BatchDateTime ,
                COLL.BillNumber ,
                LEDG.Collector ,  
                FINS.Corporation ,
                VISIT.FacilityID ,
                XFRTXN.InsuranceID ,
                XFRTXN.ManualEdit ,
                XFRTXN.AutoXferAmount ,
                XFRTXN.BillingID ,
                XFRTXN.TransactionID
        FROM    [dbo].[BarTxnInsuranceDetail] AS XFRTXN
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[BarVisits] AS VISIT ON [VISIT].[BillingID] = [XFRTXN].[BillingID]
                                                             AND [VISIT].[SourceID] = [XFRTXN].[SourceID]
                LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[BarVisitFinancialData] AS FINS ON [FINS].[BillingID] = [XFRTXN].[BillingID]
                                                             AND [FINS].[SourceID] = [XFRTXN].[SourceID]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[BarInsuranceLedger] AS LEDG ON [LEDG].[BillingID] = [XFRTXN].[BillingID]
                                                              AND [LEDG].[InsuranceID] = [XFRTXN].[InsuranceID]
                                                              AND [LEDG].[SourceID] = [XFRTXN].[SourceID]
                INNER JOIN [dbo].[BarCollectionTransactions] AS COLL ON [COLL].[BillingID] = [XFRTXN].[BillingID]
                                                              AND [COLL].[SourceID] = [XFRTXN].[SourceID]
                                                              AND [COLL].[TransactionID] = [XFRTXN].[TransactionID]
        WHERE   COLL.Type IN ( 'p', 'A', 'R', 'P', 'q', 'm', 'v', 'b' )
        **AND (ISNUMERIC(COLL.BillingID) = 1
        OR ISNUMERIC(COLL.BillingID) = 0)** 
                AND COLL.BatchDateTime BETWEEN @DateAwareFromDateTime
                AND     @DateAwareThruDateTime
```

the query runs successfully.  That WHERE clause filters nothing out.  It is also strange that SQL would interpret these as numeric values, when they are defined explicitly in COLL as VARCHAR values.  It is also interesting to note that this fix only works with the COLL table.  If instead we used XFERTXN.BillingID, it causes the same error.

I believe that this error may be a SQL bug, and was wondering if anyone noticed anything similar.  All of the columns in the table we are inserting into that are of type MONEY, have valid money values in them that are not the issue.  It appears that BillingID is the problem here, as it contains integer values but is defined as a VARCHAR on each table in the process.  SQL somehow seems to think they are money values, and fails, even though it so happens that each of the values in that column are money values.  Does anyone have any ideas as to why this error may be presented in the first code example?

Thanks!

Comment: What is the point of check if BillingID is or is not numeric? Do you have any rows in that table that have a value that isn't numeric? How many rows does this return? select * from BarCollectionTransactions where ISNUMERIC(BillingID) = 0

Comment: That statement returns 0 rows.  The point of checking BillingID is because all of the rows in BarCollectionTransactions have a numeric value in a varchar column, we believe SQL might think it's a money/numeric column.  If we remove all references and joins to tables that contain BillingID, the query runs.  We think that column is the problem.  It's raising a lot of eyebrows that adding in that WHERE clause causes the query to execute successfully, and we believe that although that where clause should and will have no effect on the number of rows to insert, the execution plan changes.

Comment: But your where predicate should be ignored because IsNumeric can only return 2 possible values and you are checking for either of them. I am guessing that either BillingID or Master_BAR_INS_XFER_TXN_FACT_NPR_0_ETL_Test_Source_No_valid_subdivisions.Patient_Account_Id is not a varchar. But that is just blind guessing because we haven't seen the table definitions.

Comment: Agreed that the WHERE predicate should be ignored because we cover the whole set of values of IsNumeric.  My best guess is that SQL is taking a different execution plan that causes success when the IsNumeric clause is added.  BillingID in the primary tables and all tables joined to is a VARCHAR, and Patient_Account_Id in Master_ is also a VARCHAR.

Comment: Also, when  we compare the estimated execution plan of the failed query to that of the successful query, the Compute Scalar is being executed before the inner joins in the successful query, and after the inner joins in the failed query.

Comment: Can you show the definition of BarTxnInsuranceDetail, or at least the column types of the columns that you're selecting?

Comment: The full definition of BarTxnInsuranceDetail is below:

 [SourceID] [varchar](3)
 [VisitID] [varchar](256)
 [BillingID] [varchar](256)
 [ClassID] [varchar](256) 
 [TransactionID] [varchar](256) 
 [InsuranceID] [varchar](256) 
 [Adjustment] [money]
 [Amount] [money]
 [AutoXferAmount] [money]
 [ExpectedReimburse] [money]
 [ManualEdit] [varchar](256)
 [NumberExpectedReciepts] [int]
 [NumberRecieptsHold] [int]
 [StatementSelect] [varchar](256)
 [RowUpdateDateTime] [datetime] 

Thank you Mark!

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to insert XFRTXN.ManualEdit (type varchar) into Manual_Transfer_Amount (type money), thus you get "Cannot convert a char value to money".

As for the the difference between your two queries, double check them to make sure this was really the only difference:

```
AND (ISNUMERIC(COLL.BillingID) = 1 OR ISNUMERIC(COLL.BillingID) = 0)
```

Comment: That WHERE clause was really the only difference.  It has no problem inserting values into those rows with that where clause as the only difference between the queries.

In Fact, changing all of out columns in the target table to VARCHAR from MONEY still throws this error in without the WHERE clause.

Comment: Furthermore, the XFRTXN.ManualEdit is always a numeric value that can be inserted into a MONEY column for anything returned with the WHERE clause intact.  The data validation has already been completed.

Comment: More information:

It turns out that when we removed a primary key clustered index on BarVisits, and force it to do a table scan, this error vanishes.  Our first thought after that was index corruption, but then recreating the index causes the problem to reappear.

Comment: Curious... when the error appears, does it also occur if you just run the SELECT part of your INSERT statement, or does it only occur if you actually try to run the INSERT?